# Using the method of charateristics. Show that $ yu_x - 3x^2yu_y = 3x^2u $ has a genereal solution $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{y}f(x^3 +y)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

$$ yu_x - 3x^2yu_y = 3x^2u $$

I then get my $\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $-3x^2$ which leads to $ \phi = y+x^3$ and $\xi = x$

I then find $u_x$ and $u_y$ by using the chain rule.

$$ u_x = \frac{du}{d\phi} \frac{d\phi}{dx} + \frac{du}{d\xi} \frac{d\xi}{dx}$$
$$ u_y = \frac{du}{d\phi} \frac{d\phi}{dy} + \frac{du}{d\xi} \frac{d\xi}{dy}$$
$$ u_x = 3x^2\frac{du}{d\phi} + \frac{du}{d\xi} $$
$$ u_y = \frac{du}{d\phi} $$

Substituting these into the equation above

$$ 3x^2y\frac{du}{d\phi} + y\frac{du}{d\xi} - 3x^2y\frac{du}{d\phi} = 3x^2u $$
$$ y\frac{du}{d\xi} = 3x^2u $$

it is at this pint where i get stuck and i am not really sure how to move forward with the problem. My first thought is to change y to $\phi - x^3$ and then say since $x=\xi$ therefore $y=\phi - \xi^3$ and therefore $3x^2u = 3\xi^2u$ but i couldn't get much further.

Apologies if similar questions have been asked, i read a few but i didn't really understand the method they were using (not saying they were wrong, im just not good enough to understand it).

Comment: I think its understanding the relationship between the chain rule and the PDE that is the issue here. If $u = u(x(t),y(t))$ for some parameter $t$ then taking the _total_ derivative of $u$ with respect to $t$ and comparing with the PDE we have \begin{align} u'(t) &=u_{x}x'(t)+u_{y}y'(t) \\ &= yu_{x}-3x^{2}y u_{y} \\ &= 3x^{2} u \\ \implies x'(t) &= y, \quad y'(t) = -3x^{2} y, \quad u'(t) = 3x^{2} u \end{align} which, by eliminating $dt$, yields the characteristic relations at the beginning of krashkovs answer below.

Comment: Hi @mattos, thank you for your comment, i don't recall ever solving one of these equations before so i am still lost on how we go about actually getting our characteristic relations in the answer below. as in what mathematical operations  do i have to do to turn:$$\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-3x^2y} = \frac{du}{3x^2u}$$ into $$c_1=y+x^3$$ and $$c_2 = uy$$ Apologies if I am missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: Because all quantities are equal, you can examine individual relations separately. Starting with the first equality \begin{align} \frac{dx}{y} &= \frac{dy}{-3x^{2}y} \\ \implies -3x^{2} dx &= dy \quad \text{(separating variables)} \\ \implies -x^{3} + c_{1} &= y \quad \text{(integrating)} \\ \implies c_{1} &= y + x^{3} \end{align} Now follow the same approach to solve one of the other equality relations (upon inspection, the _easier_ relation to examine would be the one between $y$ and $u$, though you could examine the one between $x$ and $u$ instead if you wanted).

Comment: I think I got it! $$\frac{dy}{-3x^2y}=\frac{du}{3x^2u} \\ \frac{dy}{-y} = \frac{du}{u} \\ -ln(y) = ln(u) + k \\ 1/y =  uk \\ 1/k = yu$$ where $1/k = c_2$. Thank you for the help! This community is great!

Comment: I'm not sure how you got $-\ln y \to 1/y$ in the third to fourth lines, it should just be $$- \ln y + k = \ln u \implies k = \ln u + \ln y \implies k = \ln yu \implies \tilde{k} = yu$$ I'm glad you got it now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characteristics can be found from the following system of equations

$$
\frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{-3x^2y} = \frac{du}{3x^2u}
$$

Directly solving it one may obtain

$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi_1(x, y, u) &= y+x^3 = c_1\\
\phi_2(x, y, u) &= u y = c_2
\end{aligned}
$$

General solution of PDE is written in terms of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$

$$
\begin{aligned}
F(\phi_1, \phi_2) = 0\\
F(y+x^3, u y) = 0\\
u y &= f(y+x^3)\\
u &= \frac{1}{y}f(y+x^3)
\end{aligned}
$$

where $F$ and $f$ are arbitrary functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer krashkov, i am a little unclear how you managed to get to $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ as in, what are the mathematical operations used to obtain these characteristic functions. Do you divide dy and dy and also du and dx then integrate them? if so how do you get to the functions from there? Again thank you for your help!

Comment: @Max I see that you have already understood the idea behind obtaining exact form of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. Hope everything is clear now.